# Django short description for property

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

has anyone an idea how to add custom name to property in Django model? For example, if I got property:

```
@property
def my_property(self):
     return u'Returns some calculations'
```

and I show it in admin as a column:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['my_property',]
```

Then I see "My property" column and what I need is "Property X" column. I tried with my_property.short_description and my_property.verbose_name, none of this works.

Answer (score 60):

The solution by Masatsugu Hosoi works fine, but you can also use the decorator and set short_description on the property getter (fget):

```
@property
def my_property(self):
    return u'Returns some calculations'
my_property.fget.short_description = u'Property X'
```

Answer (score 15):

I've ended up adding the field to the `ModelAdmin` class as well, redirecting to the model:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['my_property',]

    def my_property(self, object):
        return object.my_property

    my_property.short_description = _("Property X")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def _my_property(self):
    return u'Returns some calculations'  
_my_property.short_description =  'Property X'
my_property = property(_my_property)
```

Comment: Best solution. Easy and direct

Comment: except that you end up with a prop and a method that return the same

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do this with the @ decorator syntax, but you can do:

```
def my_property(self):
    return u'Returns some calculations'
property_x = property(my_property)
```

Then, in your admin class set:

```
list_display = ['whatever', 'something_else', 'property_x']
```

The capitalization isn't perfect, but it will display 'Property x'. It may be possible to get Django to display the `__doc__` for a property so you could control the formatting better, but it's a start.

You can add the doc= keyword argument as such:

```
property_x = property(my_property, doc='Property X')
```

Comment: doc=keyword would be much better. What I need is a name of column that would be localizable. For example _('Property X'). That's why I don't want Django just to capitalize property's name.
How could I use __doc__ with decorators?

Comment: Good question. I haven't had time to dig through Django's implementation of how the column names in the change list get populated.

Comment: It would be nice if they changed the behavior of list_display, so that one can customize column names, ie.: list_display = ['whatever':'First column name', 'something_else':'Second column','property_x':'Third column',]

Comment: I agree, and since all the source is available to us, we can write a patch.

Answer (score 1):

in **admin.py** into your **ModelAdmin** add this code :

```
def my_property(self , obj):
    return 'Returns some calculations'
my_property.short_description = 'Property X'
```

after that add my_property to **list_display**

```
list_display=['my_property',]
```

**like this :**

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['my_property',]

    def my_property(self , obj):
        return 'Returns some calculations'
    my_property.short_description = 'Property X'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the property class as New-style class.
So you can add all attributes you need

```
class property(property):
    """Redefine property object"""
    pass

@property
def my_property(self):
     return u'Returns some calculations'

my_property.short_description = _("Property X")
```

Actually I'm not sure it is a good practice. Anyway I don't see any contraindication.

Answer (score -1):

This thread is old, but in case someone wanders down here, the solution that works is to just add a `short_description` on the `method/property` in your class.

```
def my_property(self):
    # Some things done
my_property.short_description = 'Property'
```

This will solve the problem.

Comment: Works fine as of Django 2.1.