# Verbose name for @property

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `@property` called `name` in my

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField("Given name", max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField("Family name ", max_length=255)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Is it easily possible to specify the `verbose_name` for this property?

Comment: It is called `short_description` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: Thanks @karthikr, but that only seems to work in the Admin using `admin.ModelAdmin`. I'm looking for similar behavior using `models.Model`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need such a thing ?

Comment: I was messing around with `django-tables2` and wanted to show a `@property` in a column. Apparently the fix there is to use `verbose_name` when defining the column. There might be other examples where this would be needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django short description for property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241000/django-short-description-for-property)

Comment: re fossilet's post. you should use my_property.fget.short_description = u'Property X'.  thanks.

Answer (score 18):

A `verbose_name` cannot be set for a `@property` called `name`, but `short_description` can be used instead:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('Given name', max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField('Family name ', max_length=255)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    name.fget.short_description = 'First and last name'
```

This may not work with all Django admin classes, but it will work with the basic one.

This uses the `fget` object created by `@property` and sets a `short_description` property in it.  Django looks for that property and uses it if available.

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation the following code is suggested to give a property short description:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def my_property(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
    my_property.short_description = "Full name of the person"

    full_name = property(my_property)

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('full_name',)
```

However, this approach does not work when using Django-tables2 so the following code is needed in order to change a column name:

```
columnName = tables.Column(verbose_name='column name')
```

[Django-tables2: Change text displayed in column title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601300/django-tables2-change-text-displayed-in-column-title)

so finally I think you should use custom forms and override field verbose_name if you face such a problem.