# Verbose name for a property described in the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How do I set a `verbose_name` for the `@property`, which I described in the model, so I can see a different field name (e.g. 'subcategory') in Django Admin?

```
@property
def category_name(self):
    return self.category.name
```

I tried to set Meta, `short_description` and verbose name inside of the method -- it doesn't work.

Comment: *How* did you try to set `short_description`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set it inside model directly, instead of `Meta` and you don't need this `@property` decorator at all:

```
def category_name(self):
    return self.category.name
category_name.short_description = u'your description'
```

Comment: I think, there is no need for property decorator here?

Comment: @doniyor yes sure, no need for `@property`

Comment: yep, I would just call the property inside this function instead of `self.category.name` --> `self.category_name` and change the function name to something else

Answer (score 1):

```py
@property
def category_name(self):
    return self.category.name

category_name.fget.short_description = 'Category name'
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352815/13765033